# Joint distribution of a Normal and Truncated Normal

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, truncation

I have a random variable $X\sim \text{Normal}(\mu,\sigma)$ and have the transformation $Y=\max\{0,X\}$.  Is the distribution of $Y$ a truncated normal where it is truncated to live on the positive half of the real line?

Secondly, is there a closed form solution for the joint distribution of a Normal random variable and a truncated Normal random variable?

Comment: $Y$ is a "censored" version of $X$, not a "truncated" one, to follow established terminology -because, while it is defined in the positive half of the real line (as would be $X$ truncated from below at zero), it accumulates positive probability mass at point zero. See also this post:http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77878/likelihood-function-of-truncated-data/77961#77961

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  Secondly if I have another variable $Z\sim\text{Normal}(a,b^2)$ is there a way to calculate the joint distribution of $(Y,Z)$?

Comment: You can easily adapt the density found in the post I mentioned to your case, to obtain the density of $Y$. Then, if $Z$ is independent of $Y$, you just take their product.

Comment: And if they are not independent?

Comment: When $X>0$ they will have the usual bivariate normal density with an arbitrary correlation coefficient. When $X\le0$, are they still dependent?

Comment: If $X$ and $Z$ were dependent random variables then mustn't $Y$ and $Z$ be dependent random variables irrespective of whether or not $X>0$ or $X\leq 0$?

Comment: I don't believe so. Let $X$ and $W$ be independent standard normal variates and let $U$ independently be Bernoulli$(1/2)$. Define $Z = W$ if $X\gt 0$ and otherwise $Z = (2U-1)X$. The latter clause makes $Z$ dependent on $X$. When $X\le 0,$ $Z$ is randomly either $X$ or $-X$, giving $Z$ a standard Normal distribution conditional on $X\le 0$. Also, $Z$ has a standard Normal distribution conditional on $X\gt 0$ (by construction). Thus the distribution of $Z$ conditional on $Y=\max\{0,X\}$ is standard normal and independent of $Y$, making this $(X,Z)$ a counterexample to your conjecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to consider cases. Denote $B(y,z;\rho)$ the joint bivariate normal cumulative distribution function of two correlated variables with correlation coefficient $\rho$.

The joint support is $[0,\infty] \times (-\infty, \infty)$

For $\{Y=0, Z \in (-\infty, \infty)\}$ we have

$$P(Y=0, Z\le z) = P(X\le 0 , Z\le z) = \int_{-\infty}^{z}\int_{-\infty}^0f_{XZ}(x,z)dxdz$$

$$= B(0,z;\rho_{XZ})$$

For $\{Y>0, Z \in (-\infty, \infty)\}$ we have
$$P(Y>0, Z\le z) = P(0<X\le x , Z\le z) = \int_{-\infty}^{z}\int_{0}^xf_{XZ}(x,z)dxdz$$
$$= B(x,z;\rho_{XZ}) = B(y^+,z;\rho_{XZ})$$

the last equality because for this range $Y = X$.

Bringin together using indicator functions

$$F_{YZ}(y,z) = B(0,z;\rho_{XZ})\cdot I_{\{Y=0\}} + B(y^+,z;\rho_{XZ})\cdot (1-I_{\{Y=0\}})$$

Differentiation of the two branches of the cdf will give you the corresponding densities.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this CDF doesn't have a density because it is singular along a line $Y=0$.

Comment: What should I do @Whuber?

Comment: Do you need to do anything? Alecos has given you an explicit solution in terms of standard mathematical objects; that's a reasonable interpretation of "closed form" and it allows for simple calculation of the probability of any event.

Comment: @Whuber, is his solution correct?

Comment: Also, are (Y,Z) jointly bivariate Normal as he states above?

Comment: I do not see any such claim in this answer: the bivariate normal distribution is applied to $X$ and $Z$, not to $Y$ and $Z$.  Although I have not checked it over in detail, it definitely is the right approach (and therefore received my upvote).

Comment: I do not state that $(Y,Z)$ are jointly bivariate Normal - I _assume_ that $(X,Z)$ are jointly bivariate normal. The cdf of $(Y,Z)$ is the last expression, which is not a bivariate normal, viewed as a whole.

Comment: Sorry, I read the notation incorrectly $B(y,z;\rho)$

Comment: Last question, since Y is a transformation of X do we need a Jacobian term?

Comment: Formally yes, but for the case $Y=X$ it is equal to unity.